# When I try to run my project on MAC terminal I get this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

-> ruby init.rb

**ERROR**

Traceback (most recent call last):
1: from init.rb:1:in `<main>' init.rb:1:in` load': cannot load such file -- menu.rb (LoadError)

Comment: looks like you have a require statement or something where the path is incorrect. Either that or you don't have a menu.rb file at all. Can you edit the question to include your `init.rb` file and well as your file structure?

Comment: I have added main.rb

Comment: Geting this now *****Error****                                                                                                      Traceback (most recent call last):
 3: from init.rb:1:in `<main>'
 2: from init.rb:1:in `load'
 1: from menu.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
menu.rb:1:in `load': cannot load such file -- shop.rb (LoadError)

Comment: Again, missing the file, or the require path is in correct in the menu file. Editing the question with the code from the file(s) and the project structure would go a long way in helping us help you

Comment: Hey bro thanks did it! I know where I was wrong. Thanks a lot, you saved me!

Comment: Cool :D  I added the answer. If you want to accept it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're either missing the files in your app or your require statements have an incorrect path. If you update the requires or add the files and then require them correctly, it will solve your probelm :D